# I created an inmemory hsql database in my Junit test case. Does it fall under PUBLIC schema?

Tags: spring, junit, hsqldb, testcase

Whenever I searched about the ways to drop the inmemory database after the test cases finish executing , I found out that

'DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE'

would do the trick. And after googling for a while I figured out that HSQLDB has one catalog per database and the catalog is named PUBLIC. Does this mean that the inmemory database that i created will be deleted if I drop the public schema.

Below is the sample of how I have created the inmemory table and how I dropped the public schema:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:WEB-INF/jobtest-context.xml", "classpath:WEB-INF/batch-context.xml", "classpath:WEB-INF/jpa-context.xml", "classpath:WEB-INF/repositories-context.xml" })

public class XyzJobTest {
public XyzJobTest() {
    System.setProperty("db.username", "sa");
    System.setProperty("db.password", "");
    System.setProperty("db.driver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    System.setProperty("db.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    System.setProperty("db.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:file:test");
    System.setProperty("db.persistenceUnit", "esewa");
    System.setProperty("db.poolsize.min", "1");
    System.setProperty("db.poolsize.max", "2");
    System.setProperty("db.showSql", "true");
    System.setProperty("commissionjob.cron", "0 0 1 * *");
    System.setProperty("db.generateDdl", "true");
    System.setProperty("commission.calc.batch.size", "10");
    System.setProperty("settlementBank.code", "NRBPNK");
}
  public void dropSchema(){

    Connection connection = (Connection)       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
    Statement statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE");
}
}

I have renamed my testCase class here .
```

Comment: If you're doing this in JUnit, then the database will be dropped when the JUnit runner stops running - that is, when all the tests have completed.  Is there a reason why you need to have it dropped before then?

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB has a single catalog named PUBLIC (which you can change) and one schema named PUBLIC (which you can also change) in this catalog. Your code can create new schemas in addition to the PUBLIC schema.

If you use the DROP SCHEMA schemaName CASCADE on the PUBLIC schema and all other schemas that you may have created, everything will be cleared from the database.